# The name of Hashem in avodah zarah

Tags: avodah-zarah

I watched a video on YouTube of a gentile burning his Christian books, now that he has discovered the truth. I would love to do the same,but have a serious doubt. These books also have the name of Hashem in them. Christians believe in G-d and jesus. Is it allowed to burn, or throw away in the garbage, the name of Hashem when it's in this avoda zara? I would like to look up a source.If anyone answers english please, I don't know Hebrew. Thank you

Comment: Shulchan Aruch (334:21): If Kisvei ha'Kodesh were written by an Apikores, i.e. a devout idolater, or a Mumar to idolatry, we do not save it. Even on a weekday, we burn it with the Azkaros (mentions of Hash-m's name).

Comment: Is it allowed to be thrown in the garbage instead?

Comment: Burn would be the ideal (same like nails - g'niddh 17). But pashtus you can throw it out as well.

Comment: Nails - Avodah Zara .... Both Tuma albeit the latter is worse

Comment: @False Pashtus is the OP has no idea what pashtus means. Along with the other words from the Hebrew language she said she doesn't know.

Comment: She doesn't need to know what pashtus means to know what I mean

Comment: Thank you for your comments and help. I appreciate it